# Can I make two edge label drop in a single traversal without using union and without putting labels together?

Tags: gremlin

When I do:

```
g.V(id).as("entity").union(outE("hasType").drop(),outE("createdBy").drop())
```

both drops happen

When I do:

```
g.V(id).as("entity").outE("hasType").drop().outE("createdBy").drop()
```

only the first drop happens (might be that I am dropping `createdBy` of types)

When I do:

```
 g.V(id).as("entity").outE("hasType").drop().V(id).outE("createdBy").drop()
```

I think only the first drop happens

I know I could do something like that:

```
g.V(id).as("entity").outE("hasType","createdBy").drop();
```

but I would like to do the drops in sequence since the traversal is being built by code. So I need something like that:

```
g.V(id).as("entity").outE("hasType").drop().back("entity").out("createdBy").drop()
```

is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g.V(id).outE("hasType","createdBy").drop()
```

...is the way to go. You could build the respective array with labels in your code. However, if that doesn't work for some reason, then you can still use side-effects:

```
g.V(id).sideEffect(outE("hasType").drop()).sideEffect(outE("createdBy").drop())
```